# Problema con flexbox en angular

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

estoy teniendo un problema con flexbox. Tengo un DIV con class 'wrapper' y dentro hay otros 2 DIVs. Lo que estoy intentando en que cada uno de los DIVs se vea de un lado de la pantalla. Como dividiendo la pantalla en 2.
Adjunto el HTML

```
<div class="loading">
  <app-loading-spinner *ngIf="!owners"></app-loading-spinner>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="owners-container" *ngFor="let owner of owners">
    <p class="owner">
      <strong> Full name:</strong> {{ owner.first_name }} {{ owner.last_name }}
      <strong>| Gender:</strong> {{ owner.gender }} <strong> | Status:</strong>
      {{ owner.status }}
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="owners-details-container">
    <h2>Alguna data</h2>
    <p>en un dato</p>
    <p>en un dato</p>
    <p>en un dato</p>
    <p>en un dato</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y el CSS es:

```
.loading {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
.owner {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 50%;
}
.owner:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 4em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.owners-details-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has intentado esto:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Y otra manera empezar de zero y crear algo asi

```
<div>
    <div style="display: flex; flex: 1; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between;">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div style="width: 40%; background-color: antiquewhite;">
            <div style="padding: 12px; border: 1px blue solid;" *ngFor="let owner of owners">
                <p>
                    <strong> Full name:</strong> {{ owner.name }} {{ owner.name }}
                    <strong>| Gender:</strong> {{ owner.from }} <strong> | Status:</strong> {{ owner.to }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- right column -->
        <div style="width: 40%; background-color: rgb(216, 127, 10);">
            <div style="border: 1px red solid; padding: 12px;">
                <h2>Alguna data</h2>
                <p>en un dato</p>
                <p>en un dato</p>
                <p>en un dato</p>
                <p>en un dato</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No mires los datos de tu lista lo cambie para hacer una prueba
Y el resultado
[image: Flex]

Comment: Si, lo que sucede es que se generan 2 columnas pero se salen de la pantalla y los párrafos del ''owners-container'' se muestran de forma vertical. Y ahi no se como acomodarlo.

Comment: He modificado  mi respuesta, comprueba ahora espero que es lo que buscas

Comment: Si, con esa estructura funciono! Muchas gracias.

Comment: ahi lo hice! Gracias @marcos y Tomaz